# Is there any way to shift to previous browser tab using javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-tab

[image: Im working on a VBCS application and i have a requirement to download files onto a new tab.]

Im running an application, and after a few operations I end up at the last tab (circled in black). I need to close the red circled tab because it is a duplicate of the blue circled tab. Is there any way i can go back to the red tab and call

```
window.close()
```

on it? All the tabs are being opened through my application only. IS it even possible to navigate back to the tab? Also i cannot close the blue circled tab because even though the red circled tab is a dulicate of it, the red tab is reloading the page and the blue tab is already loaded page.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Outside of a browser extension, I don't think you get that kind of access to browser tabs. _"All the tabs are being opened through my application only."_ - then you should probably try and add them to a list of opened tabs you keep yourself, at that point.

Comment: Perhaps this puts you on the right track: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs`. I also remember theres an API that can control multiple tabs owned by the same domain, but I've forgotten the name...

Answer (score 2):

You can communicate between the tabs using `localStorage` (actually there might be even a better API for this [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)
). Anyway, this is a sketch of a solution which is open for some bugs but if you like it , it can be improved.

```
<h2>page 1</h2>
<button onclick="close_others();">close others</button>
<script>
    window.id = Math.random();
    var key = "close-but-me"

    function close_others() {
        localStorage.setItem(key, window.id);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            localStorage.removeItem(key);
        }, 2000)
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(localStorage.getItem(key))
        if (localStorage.getItem(key) && localStorage.getItem(key)!=window.id) {
            window.close();
        } 
    }, 1000)
</script>
```

```
<h2>page 2 - SAME code</h2>

<button onclick="close_others();">close others</button>
<script>
    window.id = Math.random();
    var key = "close-but-me"

    function close_others() {
        localStorage.setItem(key, window.id);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            localStorage.removeItem(key);
        }, 2000)
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(localStorage.getItem(key))
        if (localStorage.getItem(key) && localStorage.getItem(key)!=window.id) {
            window.close();
        } 
    }, 1000)
</script>
```